# drake plan fitting lmer models fails

Tags: r, lme4, drake-r-package

I am trying to fit some `lme4::lmer` models in `drake` plan, but am getting an error

> 'data' not found, and some variables missing from formula environment

If I substitute an `lm` model, it works.

Here is a reproducible example

```
library(drake)
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Matrix'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:drake':
#> 
#>     expand

plan_lm <- drake_plan(
  dat = iris,
  mod = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = dat)
)

make(plan_lm)
#> ℹ Consider drake::r_make() to improve robustness.
#> ▶ target dat
#> ▶ target mod

plan_lmer <- drake_plan(
  dat1 = iris,
  mod1 = lmer(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = dat1)
)

make(plan_lmer)
#> ▶ target dat1
#> ▶ target mod1
#> x fail mod1
#> Error: target mod1 failed.
#> diagnose(mod1)$error$message:
#>   'data' not found, and some variables missing from formula environment
#> diagnose(mod1)$error$calls:
#>   lme4::lFormula(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = dat1, 
#>     control = list("nloptwrap", TRUE, 1e-05, TRUE, FALSE, list(
#>         "ignore", "stop", "ignore", "stop", "stop", "message+drop.cols", 
#>         "warning", "stop"), list(list("warning", 0.002, NULL), 
#>         list("message", 1e-04), list("warning", 1e-06)), list()))
#>   lme4:::checkFormulaData(formula, data, checkLHS = control$check.formula.LHS == 
#>     "stop")
#>   base::stop("'data' not found, and some variables missing from formula environment", 
#>     call. = FALSE)
Created on 2020-07-29 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This edge case is an instance of https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/1012 and https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/1163. `drake` creates its own environments to run commands, so the environment with `dat` is different from the environment where the model actually runs. There are good reasons `drake` does this, and the behavior is not going to change, so this issue is unfortunately permanent unless `lme4` changes. The best workaround I can offer is to create the formula in the target's environment at runtime, something like the reprex below. You have to manually force the data and the formula to be in the same environment. I recommend writing a custom function to do this.

```r
library(drake)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lme4))

fit_lmer <- function(dat) {
  envir <- environment()
  envir$dat <- dat
  f <- as.formula("Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject)", env = envir)
  lme4::lmer(f, data = dat)
}

plan <- drake_plan(
  dat = sleepstudy,
  mod = fit_lmer(dat)
)

make(plan)
#> ▶ target dat
#> ▶ target mod
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

By the way, please consider avoiding the iris dataset if you can: https://armchairecology.blog/iris-dataset/

Answer (score 2):

I can work around the problem by reassigning within the new target

```
plan <- drake_plan(
  dat = sleepstudy,
  mod =  {dat <- dat
    lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), dat)
  }
)
make(plan)
```

Or following https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/1163, using `readd(dat)`